# Event notifications Twilio Video

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio

Is it possible to receive notifications on events from Twilio Video on client side through the token the same way as for the Twilio Voice, aka as room.on('participantConnected'), or every event is coming through the status callback URL set in the Room settings? Through the webhook, the events are arriving as soon as i take an action through the client, but otherwise, no notification appears as per the example from the Twilio Video website:

```
Twilio.Video.connect('$TOKEN', {name:'my-new-room'}).then(function(room) {
  console.log('Successfully joined a Room: ', room);
  room.on('participantConnected', function(participant) {
    console.log('A remote Participant connected: ', participant);
  })
}, function(error) {
    console.error('Unable to connect to Room: ' +  error.message);
});
```

Right now i am using a webhook of form

```
app.post('/video',(req, res) => {
    room = req.body;
room.on('disconnected', function (room, error) {
    console.log('a');
});
});
```

Comment: What events are you trying to get from Twilio Video? Are you find that `participantConnected` isn't firing, or are you looking for other events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i kinda figured it out and it's a bit wtf... so apparently if you are a local participant, your events won't appear in the room _events to be picked up by room.on('event'). They will appear in the room->localParticipant-> _events room.localParticipant.on('event') which is a bit weird in my opinion, but i'm ok with that... not quite straight forward, but it does the job once you figure it out. Hope this will help someone :)

Comment: Do you have a sample of your code? I am working off a similar example but am not able to get ANY events to fire so the camera turns on and the user joins the room but no video preview shows up on the page as the functions like participantConnected() or trackAdded() never fire.

Comment: yea, i put the code that i'm using for the events in a paste bin here https://pastebin.com/xya20a4G   hope it helps

Comment: Thank you very much Adrian!